# what's the difference between weighting and transforming?

Tags: spss, data-transformation, weighted-regression

In regression analysis, what's the difference between weighting and transforming when it comes to spreading residuals? For example, we need to weight the model $y=ax+b$ by $1/x$, isn't it just multiply/re-scaling $1/x$ on both sides of the equation?
below is some content from my textbook, I totally don't understand it
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That definition seems unnecessarily confusing. Option 1 and 2 look like the same thing to me. Assume that you know your residual variance is a function of X e.g. Var(u) = s*X where u is the residual, then by scaling u by 1/sqrt(X), by rules of variances Var(u/sqrt(X)) = (1/X)*Var(u), which now evaluates to s. Thus by scaling your model according to 1/sqrt(X) makes this simple model homoscedastic. By the same logic, this is equivalent to weighting your model by 1/X in the standard equation for calculating the slope coefficient